# "Che ne fatto dono" oppure "che ne ha fatto dono"?

Tags: grammar, verbs

In un'informazione riferente a un'istituzione ho letto:

> Alle ore 12, nel nostro giardino verrà inaugurata la Fontana-Scultura creata appositamente per questo spazio dall’artista ..., *che ne fatto dono* all’Istituto.

L'espressione "che ne fatto dono" in questa frase mi è sembrata strana.  È corretta? Non dovrebbe essere "che ne ha fatto dono"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sì, è un errore,
'che ne ha fatto dono' è indubbiamente la forma corretta.

Answer (score 4):

Il participio passato `fatto` non può essere usato da solo in questo contesto.

Probabilmente è stato omesso l'ausiliare avere. In aggiunta alle altre risposte, si possono ottenere altre forme accettabili cambiando il tempo del verbo, ad esempio usando il presente o il passato remoto:

> che (nell'occasione) ne fa dono
>
> che ne fece dono

Answer (score 1):

Senza alcun dubbio "che ne ha fatto dono".

Comment: Vero, ma non aggiunge molto a una risposta già esistente...